# What's the easiest way to get the HTML output of an actix-web endpoint handler to be rendered properly?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I've defined an endpoint with actix-web like so:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct RenderInfo {
    filename: String,
}

fn render(info: actix_web::Path<RenderInfo>) -> Result<String> {
    // ...
}
```

```
App::new()
    .middleware(middleware::Logger::Default())
    .resource("/{filename}", |r| r.get().with(render))
```

The problem I've run into is that the raw HTML gets displayed in the browser rather than being rendered. I assume the content-type is not being set properly.

Most of the actix-web examples I saw used `impl Responder` for the return type, but I wasn't able to figure out how to fix the type inference issues that created. The reason seems to have something to do with file operations returning a standard `failure::Error`-based type. It looks like actix_web requires implementation of a special `WebError` to block unintended propagation of errors. For this particular instance, I don't really care, because it's more of an internal tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [actix-web examples](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/e30915d98d8b9e44b0f27ad361c5f2af14bb02b2/basics/src/main.rs), use [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.13/actix_web/struct.HttpResponse.html):

```
fn welcome(req: &HttpRequest) -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    println!("{:?}", req);

    // session
    let mut counter = 1;
    if let Some(count) = req.session().get::<i32>("counter")? {
        println!("SESSION value: {}", count);
        counter = count + 1;
    }

    // set counter to session
    req.session().set("counter", counter)?;

    // response
    Ok(HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::OK)
        .content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8")
        .body(include_str!("../static/welcome.html")))
}
```